# Modifying SharePoint Lists RSS URLs

Tags: rss

I want to re-use the content from a current list in a different custom web part that reads RSS. However, I do not want all the content from this list, I just want some of the articles to be displayed on this other custom web part.

In order to filter them, I have created a new column (IsSpotlight (Yes | No) and a new View. However, when I get the RSS URL for this list, it doesn't take into consideration the View I am using or filter I am applying. How can I edit the list RSS URL to show just the list items I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the View Settings for your newly created view.  You should see a RSS iscon directly under the web address of the view.  Click that, and that is the RSS feed for your particular view.  Use that in your custom web part.

Comment: That I can get... but it displays all the list items and I only want those that meet one criteria

Comment: I've verified that it does not. Are you sure you are in the Modify his View menu for the particular view you'd like to use? You should end up with a URL that looks like /_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=8a41a118%2D0206%2D45a8%2D9699%2Ded067b84527a&View=cd385f0a%2Dd22b%2D4f88%2D96c1%2D45a9fa0d445f

Comment: You were absolutely right PirateEric! I had to manually create the URL combining the RSS list ID and the View ID, but it totally works! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try relying on ListData.svc which exposes Atom feeds using a OData. Almost every single list in SharePoint 2010 is also available via this REST WCF Service. In this way you could use OData queries to filter only records of interest for you (see here http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions/#SystemQueryOptions or more preciselly http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). If you do no know how to build your query I would recomand LinqPad a free tool (use .NET 3.5 version as it is the same .NET framework version with SharePoint, even though OData doesn't much care! - find example here http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1179&page=2)